# Fetching data in Typescript But unable to render it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch, react-dom

I am relatively new to typescript and Iv have been trying to render data from a backend server i'm running on my machine but *i can't seem to get it to render.*

**How it works or at least how i intend for it to work**

My movies component is using a unfetch's fetch function to get data from the backend server

**Movies.tsx**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

import { getPopularMovies } from './Client';
import { Result } from './Interfaces';


const Movies = () => {

    const [topMovies, setTopMovies] = useState<Result[]>([]);
    const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);


    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPopularMovies();
    }, [])

    const fetchPopularMovies = () => 
    { 
        // Help Render appropriate loading animation while fetching
        setIsFetching(true)
        
        getPopularMovies()
        .then( res => res.json()
        .then(movies => {
        setTopMovies(movies)
        setIsFetching(current => !current)
        }))

    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            {topMovies && topMovies.map((movie, key )=> {
                return (
                    <div key={key}>
                        <h1>{movie.title}</h1>
                        <p>{movie.overview}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Movies
```

The 'fetchPopularMovies' function is found in **Client.tsx**

```
import fetch from "unfetch"

// ex: proxied API request to -> api/popular
export function getPopularMovies(){
    return fetch('/api/popular')
}

// ex: proxied API request to -> api/movie/1145
export function getMovieDetails(id: number){
    fetch(`/api/movie/${id}`)
}

// ex: proxied API request to -> api/search?query="Cruella"
export function searchMovie(substring: string){
    fetch(`/api/search?query=${substring}`)
}
```

the endpoints are being proxied and everything is working just fine on this end.
**Interfaces.ts**

```
export interface Result {
    adult: boolean;
    backdrop_path: string;
    id: number;
    title: string;
    original_language: string;
    original_title: string;
    overview: string;
    poster_path: string;
    media_type: string;
    genre_ids: number[];
    popularity: number;
    release_date: string;
    video: boolean;
    vote_average: number;
    vote_count: number;
}

export interface Root {
    page: number;
    results: Result;
    total_pages: number;
    total_results: number;
    
}
```

and my **App.tsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Movies from './Movies';

export default function App ()
{
  return (
    <div>
      <Movies />
    </div>
  )
};
```

The data is being pulled from the server successfully but i'm unable to render it in it in the DOM

**UPDATE**
The problem is rendering the received data to the DOM. Not the fetching, everything works fine fetching wise.

```
[
 { 
  page: 1
  results: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
  total_pages: 1000,
  total_results: 20000,
 }
]
```

**UPDATE 2.0**
So i think i should add that i did change the react version from 16 to 18 to add React Hooks support and the problem could possibly stem from that as well.
My updated package.json  is as follows

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "movie-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "23.3.10",
    "@types/node": "10.12.18",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.2",
    "typescript": "3.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:15468",
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: what is the problem exactly? place a `console.log(movies)` and update your answer with this output

Comment: The problem is with Rendering the received data.

Comment: Try to change the setter to setIsFetching(false)

Comment: `movies` looks like being placed in `results`. so your code should be like `setTopMovies(movies.results)` ?

Comment: @MrBeans Changed it, still no difference. The state of that function was intended for aesthetic a loading animation so it should have any effect on the rendering.

Comment: @irous i am still unable to render even after making those changes

Comment: @Bright try `setTopMovies(movies[0].results)`

Comment: @irous you genius it worked 

Answer (score 0):

In the Root interface make results: Result[] beacuse from the backend ypu are getting array of results
Hope this helps

Comment: Hey, the problem is different as he is setting the response object in movies which is not the result he is looking for his expected result which should be used in setTopMovies will be movies[0].results.

which is already mentioned in the comments bellow to the question.
please try to solve the question which is asked. as it might be misleading for others :)